# Prevent HDD unmount in Nautilus

Tags: mount, hard-drive, nautilus, desktop-environments, fstab

I've 1 SSD for OS and 3 HDD's for data.

Starting with my first 3 TB drive it was mounted to `/media/[user]`. Unfortunately this HDD was unmountable by user in Nautilus.

Using some forum's I've found that I should mount this HDD in `/mnt/` instead auto automount in `/media/[user]`

-> This worked.

Now I've added two more data drives 4TB and 6TB. Have created the same partition scheme and had mounted both drives to /mnt, same as 1st .

Relevant lines from `/etc/fstab`

```
LABEL=...-3tb /mnt/...-3tb auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=...-4tb /mnt/...-4tb auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=...-6tb /mnt/...-6tb auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Unfortunately 4+6TB drives where unmountable in Nautilus and not shown at "On This Computer". My old 3TB drive is shown in "On This Computer" and not unmountable in Nautilus.

[image: Screenshot Nautilus]

What can I do that both new drive 4+6TB so the same as my 1st data (3TB) drive? I want to prevent unmount from Nautilus UI.

Comment: Execute "sudo mount -a" in the terminal. This will re-execute the mounts and may throw errors for your drives that do not mount as expected.

Comment: There was no output. So I assume everything is fine and correct mounted. Mounting seems not my problem. The problem is still that both new data drives can be unmounted by user, even it's mounted within `/mnt`

Comment: One of your options is "nofail", so errors, if any, will be ignored. Check the output of the "mount" command. It might be that the other drives are automatically mounted under /media and not through fstab

Comment: All disks are mounted at desired locations...

    /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/...-3tb type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,x-gvfs-show)
    /dev/sdc1 on /mnt/...-4tb type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,x-gvfs-show)
    /dev/sdd1 on /mnt/...-6tb type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,x-gvfs-show)

Comment: No more ideas? From my point the mount is working as desired except the umount option in Nautilus. Can't see what can be different to the 3TB data drive.

Comment: If all else fails, a workaround would be to remove the x-gvfs-show option.

Comment: Removing this Flag the drive is hidden at the left side, but not visible at the right side. 3TB data drive is visible.

And of course... 3 TB drive has the visible option active.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRAuy.png